# How do i make my code move from one line to a different line that occurred before it?

Tags: python

I have not a clue what I'm doing. I have discovered python through my ICT class and am trying to find how to go back a line of code for a small game.   [Image of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nWsI5.png)

On line 20 I want it to send you back to the choice of where to move and what to do.

Comment: Please post the code as a text in your code tag in your editor, not as a picture.

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Teach me this basic programming technique” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.

Comment: Python code executes sequentially (except when dealing with asynchronous actions, threads, etc), so you'll need to structure your code such that it flows logically. Learn how to write control flow structures such as loops, conditions, and functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try placing your logic inside a `while` loop. E.g. :

```
while True:
    Choice1 = input()
    if Choice1 == '1':
        # do stuff
    if Choice1 == '2':
        # do stuff
    if Choice1 == '3':
         # do stuff
```

All you need to add is a `break` statement in order to **exit** the loop when some sort of condition defined by you has been met.

For example, if you only want to repeat getting the user choice if `Choice1` is `3`, you would add a `break` statement in the other two conditions (for `Choice1` = `1` or `2`)

Answer (score 0):

you must use

```
while(True):
     print("++++")
     print("++++")
     print("++++") 
     c=input(">>>")
     if(c=='e')
        break
     elif(c=='r'):
        . . . ..
     elif....
     ....
```